# Is IOrderedEnumerable<T> an inherently immutable collection? Should/can I yield?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I may not quite have my head around the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` collection.

If I have a field, `my_field` of type `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, and I wish to return it from a public property getter, can I simply `return my_field;`? I'm used to `yield`ing results to an `IEnumerable<T>` to prevent external modification to an internally held collection, but it seems that this may not be necessary or may not even be possible in the case of an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Is that right?

So I couldn't declare a return type of `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and `yield` results in an arbitrary order, such that the ordering is defined by the structure of the code rather than a property-based comparison of `IComparable<T>`s? Does it follow that `T` in an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` must always implement `IComparable<T>`?

Are there classes in the .NET API that implement this interface, or does the type only get generated at runtime through the use of LINQ extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely return an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`; it is immutable.

It's only implemented by the internal `OrderedEnumerable` class in `System.Linq`, which is also immutable.